# MQ Load Testing using JMETER for JMS Point-to-Point Messaging

Tags: jms, jmeter, ibm-mq

I want to perform MQ load testing using JMETER for JMS Point-to-Point Messaging. I am able to connect and send request message for single connection to single remote queue. Can we establish multiple channel connection using same connection factory and send message to different queues. I have establish approximately 1500 channel connection with 1500 dedicated remote queues. I am using JMETER version 2.11

Answer (score 1):

If you mean using a different uniquely named SVRCONN channels then no.  The Channel specified in the connection factory can't be changed. To simulate 1 channel per connection  you would need to create a connection factory for each channel.

However, there is no technical reason you cannot use the same channel for multiple queues simply by referencing the same connection factory for each test.  Performance wise, there really won't be a difference between using 1500 instances of the same channel and 1500 individually named channels.

You may need to adjust the number of instances that that given channel and/or be started from a single client if you expect all 1500 to go at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for reply !                                                         I want to establish one channel connection per queue till 1500 connection which can run parallel. I am not getting number of instances here . Does it mean the multiple instance of same channel connection.

Comment: I guess i may be missing what you mean by "channel" connection.  If in the context of the host/port/channel that is configured in the connection factory, then you can just reuse that. The only limitation may be on the Queue manager side in how many instances of a channel or how many connections you can have.

Comment: But in real scenario, we have different clients with their separate channel connection. So , I thought to simulate the same way. If i reuse the same channel , How will I test the load on MQ server.

Comment: Still need clarification on what you mean by "channel connection".  Part of the connection to WMQ is to specify a channel, which is an object that is defined on the queue manager.  Whether or not this is what you are referring to is what needs clarified.

Comment: yeah , I am referring to the same, the channel which we create in Queue Manager and we give this channel name to the client application for connecting to queue manager and send the message.